# Make on-hover ::before element not appear during initial click

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

So I have this link item animation where by default, it's just text (:hover makes it change color), but if the link has the class of ".linke-active", :hover now adds an animated underline via a ::before pseudoelement.

So what I did was this:

```
&.link-active {
position: relative;

&::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%
    transition: 250ms ease-in-out;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;
}

&:hover, &:focus {

    &::before {
        transform: scaleX(1);
    }
}}
```

So it's pretty straightforward.

It behaves perfectly when I move my mouse over the active link, and when I move my mouse over the inactive link.

My problem is that when I do the INITIAL CLICK that leads to the link gaining the .link-active the :before psuedoelement is there automatically, and since my mouse is obviously ON the link during the click, the psuedolement is in it's hover-state.

Is there any way to make the pseudolement NOT be in it hover-state on the initial click? Or is there a better way to trigger this style ruleset?

Thanks!

Comment: What you can do is set in the before pseudo an animation that lasts say 1 minute, and that changes from scaleX(0) to scaleX(0). It won't have any effect, obviously, but will prevent the hover effect for the duration of the animation

Comment: @vals - your solution worked. Thanks.

Comment: Happy that it helped !